# Google OAuth 2.0 with JWT for authentication in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger

I've a requirement where, I need to use Google OAuth 2.0 with JWT for authentication in .NET web API.I need to retrieve the accesstoken in my code. How can I implement this? Also I'm using Swagger.

I created the client_id and client_secret. I'm able to login from Swagger using the Authorize button. But I can't get the callback method, so that I can retrieve the token details.

Comment: It'd be better if you'd share the snippet itself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example